# Pycharm Flask server run config says Flask isn't installed, won't set the FLASK_APP variable

Tags: flask, pycharm

I have written a Flask app called "lingua" using PyCharm Professional 2019.2.3. Everything works. The unit tests pass when run from the test configuration. I can run the server from the command line.
However, when I run it from the PyCharm run configuration it doesn't work because the `FLASK_APP` environment variable is not set.

```
FLASK_APP not set
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 1
In folder /Users/wmcneill/src/lingua
/Users/wmcneill/src/lingua/venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --module --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 62823 --file flask run
pydev debugger: process 53132 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.6817.19)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
pydev debugger: process 53137 is connecting

 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 274-123-483
```

When you try to get the server page you get a `flask.cli.NoAppException` error. The same thing happens if you explicitly set `FLASK_APP=lingua` in the environment variables of the run configuration. Same results if the "Target type" is "Module name", "Script path", or "Custom". The "Python Interpreter" path in the configuration is correct.

Furthermore, there is a red "x" on the configuration and an erroneous error message at the bottom of the configuration screen that reads "Warning: Flask 0.12 or higher required".

[image: Flask configuration error]

This warning is incorrect.

```
$ flask --version
Python 3.6.8
Flask 1.1.1
Werkzeug 0.16.0
```

Furthermore, the Flask server configuration worked on PyCharm yesterday, and I don't know what has changed since then. I have intermittently seen this problem on other PyCharm Flask projects. It comes and goes. I can't figure out what is triggering it.

Any idea what this problem is or how I can debug it?

Comment: Is python interpreter correctly configured in the configuration?

Comment: Yes. The interpreter is configured correctly.